# Django: String representation of models

Tags: python, django

I would like my models to have two string representations: one that is displayed in the backend logs for debugging purposes, and a cleaner one that is displayed to end users when the model is represented in the HTML. Right now, I'm just overriding `__unicode__()`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 24):

You can also try `__repr__` and `__str__` for your logging/debugging purposes. It is possible (at least it should be this way) that your logger/debugger uses `repr( object )` to log your objects.

Comment: Indeed, `__repr__` is used for debugging / internal representation, and either `__unicode__` or `__str__` for general use. This should have more upvotes.

Answer (score 8):

Use properties

```
class SomeThing( models.Model ):
    foo=
    bar= 
    baz=
    def __unicode__( self ):
        return "{0} {1}".format( self.foo, self.bar )
    @property
    def details( self ):
        return repr( dict( foo=self.foo, bar=self.bar, baz=self.baz ) )
```

Now you can log  `someObject.details`

Comment: What about that `__repr__` attribute? Can that be used somehow? So `__unicode__` is good to display the string in e.g. admin, and the `details` is good to dump the object to logs?